# Automatic reply to only one sender

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, automation, reply

How can I activate an automatic reply to only one sender?

I'm using MS Outlook 2010 professional.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple rule in 2010 to handle this just follow the below.

Home Ribbon > Rules > Manage rules & Alerts > New Rule...

From here we want to select 2nd from bottom `Apply rule on messages I receive`

[image: Rules and alerts]

## Which condition(s) do you want to check

### Step 1

Select `from people or public group`

### Step 2

Click on `from people or public group` highlighted in blue at the bottom of the window and select the person who you wish to send an auto reply

## What do you want to do with the message?

### Step 1

Select `Reply using a specific template`

### Step 2

Click on `Reply using a specific template` and select a OFT template to reply with

---

the next two steps are to be performed as you chose eg. naming and adding exemptions just make sure on the final step before you hit finish make sure the `Turn on this rule` is checked